# Suitable translation for maxim statements

Tags: grammaire, infinitif, formulation-idiomatique

Occasionally I'd like to write something in French that is of a maxim form:

> To be A is to be B

E.g.: “to be loved, is to be known”

This is somewhere between uncommon and idiomatic in structure, so it's difficult to translate.  My best guesses are pretty straightforward, but I'd like some expert advice.  Is there even a straightforward translation of this?

Maybe “Être aimé, c'est d'être connu” or “Être aimé, être connu”?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You were close, the proper way would be:

> Être aimé, c'est être connu.

Comment: the comma is optional.

Comment: @AnneAunyme Je n'en mettrais pas ma main à couper...

Comment: http://grammaire.cordial-enligne.fr/manuels/U_VIRG.htm En particulier on ne met pas de virgule entre le sujet et le verbe.

Comment: @AnneAunyme Le sujet est « c' ». « Être aimé » n'est pas le sujet mais apporte une précision qui permet de le comprendre.  On ne mettrait pas de virgule si la phrase était « Être aimé est être connu », mais ce n'est pas le cas ici. *On met une virgule devant ces mots ou expressions qui nous aident à définir notre pensée : C'EST, C'EST-À-DIRE, EN D'AUTRES TERMES, NOTAMMENT, AUTREMENT DIT, etc.*  http://francite.net/education/cyberprof/page12.html

Comment: au temps pour moi

Comment: @L'aditdabenlà  *Qui bene amat bene castigat* → Qui bien aime, bien chatie. La virgule était là pour indiquer une pause dans le discours qui n'est plus présente dans « Qui aime bien chatie bien ».

Comment: @jlliagre Réf. [_Ac.4_](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/academie4/ch%C3%A2tier) vs. [_Ac.8_](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/academie8/ch%C3%A2tier). Merci, mais pourquoi donc n'est-elle plus présente cette pause ? Ça ferait sans doute une bonne question...